Treemap clickdata and staticplot
I want a treemap that doesn't expand or collapse. For that I found that if you set
dcc.Graph(id = 'treemap', config = {'staticPlot':True}, fig = fig)

would do the job. But then, you are not able to get clickData.
So is there a way to keep the clickData while having a static plot?
